# How to type hint function with a callable argument and default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am trying to type hint the arguments of a function that takes a callable, and has a default argument (in the example below `set`)

```py
from typing import Callable, List
T = TypeVar("T")
def transform(data: List[int], ret_type: Callable[[List[int]], T] = set) -> T:
    return ret_type(data)

a = [1, 2, 3]
my_set: Set = transform(a)
```

The above code triggers the following error message from mypy `mypy3: Incompatible default for argument "ret_type" (default has type "Type[Set[Any]]", argument has type "Callable[[List[int]], T]")`

What should be the correct type of `ret_type` ?

**EDIT**

The below code although not ideal works fine (cf @chepner comment)

```py
from typing import cast, Any, Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def transform(data: Any, ret_type: Callable[..., T] = cast(Callable, set)) -> T:
    return ret_type(data)
```

Comment: it has recognised `set` as the class itself rather than the constructor function, as a workaround you could try `lambda x: set(x)` as the default value

Comment: I have the error `mypy3: Incompatible default for argument "ret_type" (default has type "Callable[[Any], Set[Any]]", argument has type "Callable[[Any], T]")`

Comment: voting to close as I think it's unclear what you're trying to achieve and it's difficult to answer properly without a well-defined question. You're asking a question about type hints but you're explicitly using `Any` (you're also missing the generic parameter to `Set` which I think is relevant), and your function doesn't work with any old object for your default value: you can't make a `set` out of just anything.

Comment: `set` can take a `List[int]` as an argument, but it cannot produce a value of an arbitrary type (represented by `T`), only a value of type `set`.

Comment: @joel: I am trying to find the right type hint for `ret_type`, what type is `data` or whether this function works with any `Callable` and `data` is irrelevant. Anyway, I've replaced `Any` by `List[int]` to remove noise.

Comment: @chepner: that's not the error though AFAIK, the issue is that `mypy` interprets `set` as the class itself rather than the constructor as @Anentropic pointed out.

Comment: At the type level, there's no difference. As far as the type checker is concerned, `set` is a callable; the distinction between class and constructor for that class are irrelevant.

Comment: Replacing `T` with `Any` fixes the error, but too generally; it doesn't constrain `transform` to return a value of the same type that `ret_type` returns.

Comment: You can also use `cast(Callable[...], set)` to tell the type checker "don't worry, `set` is fine", though that's understandably less the ideal.

Comment: @ldc At least, I would *assume* that `mypy` can recognize `set` as a callable as well as a type. And I may be getting confused over the quantification of `T`. (*Does* it get bound to `set` when `set` is the argument?)

Comment: The fact the `lambda x: set(x)` fails with different error shows there is a problem with inference for default arg values, not just that `set` is recognised as a type rather than a constructor. Note here https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e646504bd00a3ccff8f536e568cb0474 if you get rid of the default arg and just pass `set` as an arg at the call site then mypy has no problem. Alternatively if you change the `Any` for what `set` can accept e.g. `Iterable[int]` it doesn't help at all https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a3d721cbc9beb291870f7c2a4e951a7f

Comment: I found out that removing arguments for Callable make it work so `set` can be recognised as a valid `Callable`. Alternative is indeed to cast `set` to `Callable` -> https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b92c6f800474a9992cb6dc30ea5c237f

Comment: this all seems like bugs in type inference by mypy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [@overload](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading) for correctly type hinting of function with default argument for your case:

```
from typing import Callable, List, TypeVar, overload, Set

T = TypeVar("T")

@overload
def transform(data: List[int]) -> Set[int]: ...

@overload
def transform(data: List[int], ret_type: Callable[[List[int]], T]) -> T: ...
    
# untyped implementation
def transform(data, ret_type = set):
    return ret_type(data)

a = [1, 2, 3]
my_set: Set = transform(a)
```