# How to set typehint for default type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, type-variables

I'm trying to set correct typehint for default type in this situation

```py
from typing import TypeVar


class Foo:
    pass


class FooBar(Foo):
    pass


T = ...


def baz(type_: type[T] = Foo) -> T:
    return type_()
```

Already tried to use

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Foo)
```

But mypy said:

```
Incompatible default for argument "type_" (default has type "type[Foo]", argument has type "type[T]")  [assignment]
    def baz(type_: type[T] = Foo) -> T:
                             ^~~
```

Comment: Does `type[Foo]` not work in this case? I believe that will match both `Foo` (as a type) and any subclassing types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint function with a callable argument and default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034438/how-to-type-hint-function-with-a-callable-argument-and-default-value)

Comment: And https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for details, but I already read it. I don't want to use big unions, cause it looks ugly and makes my code bad readable. Is there any other way to set T?

Comment: Seems, it will be available in 3.12: https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/

Comment: This doesn't seem related to 696 tomme

Comment: You don't need unions, you need two overloads, and you can't make `mypy` happy with default arg and typevar at the same time due to the issue linked above. PEP696 is irrelevant - it gives opportunity for setting default *type variable* value, not affecting runtime (it just replaces `Any` resolution which is sometimes inconvenient with user-provided default).

Answer (score 0):

Just not to leave this question unanswered: to make `mypy` happy with typevar-typed argument with default value, you need `overload`ed definition due to [this open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737).

Implementation signature is used only for body typechecking in such case, so it can use the upper bound of type variable everywhere. External callers will see what you expect them to see

```py
from typing import TypeVar, overload

class Foo:
    pass

class FooBar(Foo):
    pass


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Foo)

@overload
def baz() -> Foo: ...
@overload
def baz(type_: type[T]) -> T: ...
def baz(type_: type[Foo] = Foo) -> Foo:
    return type_()
    
reveal_type(baz(Foo))  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo"
reveal_type(baz())  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo"
reveal_type(baz(FooBar))  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.FooBar"
```

Here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=2a8234f38b56daa22c95cf46326ecf05) with this implementation.